# Are Nobel laureates "at least 22 times more likely to partake as an amateur actor, dancer, magician or other type of performer"?

Tags: psychology

There was an opinion piece in the New York Times titled [Do You Have to Be a Jerk to Be Great?](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/07/29/opinion/work-relationships.html) in which David Brooks cites from a book called "Range" by David Epstein (emphasis added):

> In the first place, being monomaniacal may not even be good for your work. Another book on my summer reading list was “Range,” by David Epstein. It’s a powerful argument that generalists perform better than specialists.
>
> The people who achieve excellence tend to have one foot outside their main world. **“Compared to other scientists, Nobel laureates are at least 22 times more likely to partake as an amateur actor, dancer, magician or other type of performer,” Epstein writes.**

I don't own the book and haven't found any information about how the data was gathered. 22 times sounds unrealistically high and I'm wondering where you'd even get data for normal scientists to compare to nobel laureates.

Is there any evidence for this claim?

Comment: I am not good at statistics, but  per Wikipedia in the years from 1901 to 2017 there have been 813 nobel laureates (plus 24 Organisations, which I would presume do not dance or do magic tricks) altogether. Comparing that to the hundreds of thousands of active scientists is almost certainly meaningless.

Comment: That might be very difficult to put into numbers. Does grade school Christmas pageant count? Does entering a science fiction convention costume contest count?  Would attending a performance of this http://startrekultimatevoyage.com/ dressed as a Klingon count?

Comment: At first glance, looks like it's from Figure 2 in [this PDF](https://www.psychologytoday.com/files/attachments/1035/arts-foster-scientific-success.pdf) (2008), with the figure given on printed-page 54 of the same.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Naw, the sample sizes being very different isn't a problem so long as they're both large enough.  Larger sample sizes are never a bad thing, even if increasing one sample size would cause it to become different from another sample population that it's being compared to.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Why do you say it's almost certainly meaningless because of the number of active scientists?

Comment: Some Nobel awards weren't given to scientists. The "peace prize" is an entire category not typically given to scientists. It's also a bit political too (i.e. subjective), so now we may have a strange situation where we might say "selection bias", but would that mean to say that the Nobel deciding committees consider former performers over non-performers? What a weird claim.

Comment: @Eike I think that if those 813 were really 22 times more likely to behave in a certain way compared to the average population this would be statistically significant, even if the sample size of nobel laureates is small. But I agree that arriving at such a number seems very difficult. I'm not sure about the conventions here and how much of my own thoughts (without proper backup) I should put into the question. Thanks to Barry Harrison for fixing up the question.

Comment: The 22x figure is kind of a cherry-pick, because the difference in participation between Nobel Laureates and the generic scientist population in that one field is much more extreme; the more typical value across the arts is a factor of 2-3 (which I readily believe).  Looking at the graphs, I would guess it is a combination of small sub-sample (only 5% of Nobel participate in performing arts, or maybe 40 in all) and some sort of data bias in the survey representing all scientists.

Comment: @Nat I would consider your link an answer. I **strongly** encourage you to answer especially because, given several hours, there will probably be an answer composed of just that link.

Comment: @BarryHarrison Thanks!  You have a good point, but for personal reasons, I'm trying to avoid writing too many posts lately.  If anyone would like to write up the bit on the linked article, please feel free!

Comment: @Nat I will not write it up as I did not contribute anything.

Comment: @Voo I didn't actually have to fix anything up. Your original question was great. I hope you'll get a similarly great answer!

Comment: "More likely to partake" **in what**? There seems to be some context missing from the quote.